# HM-10 only works when holding button

Tags: bluetooth

My HM-10 bluetooth module is behaving weird.

In order to have it operate normally, I have to keep holding the small black button on it. If I ever release the button, it just disconnects from my phone (if it was connected) and doesn't show on the bluetooth devices list anymore, and its red LED light becomes low, not bright as usual.

It operated normally before.

How can I fix this?

What would some possibles causes be for this weird behavior?

UPDATE: picture showing the button on lower right corner.
[image: HM-10 with button on lower right corner]

Comment: What button? I see no button on the HM-10...

Comment: @Majenko I uploaded a picture

Comment: That isn't on the HM-10, that's on the breakout board the HM-10 is soldered to. No idea what the button is supposed to do, since I don't see it on any of the breakouts on google...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I just had to connect the RX/TX jumpers. There was no real issue.**

I though connecting the power jumpers was enough to just see HM-10 on my phone, since I didn't care about any data. Turns out if the RX/TX jumpers are not connect, the module behaves weird.

Comment: I'm sure everyone is glad you solved your problem, but this isn't really a valid answer - there are no apparent "RX/TX jumpers" in your picture.  To be a valid answer, this needs to be something which could make sense to someone else holding that module, and not only to you.

Comment: Accept your own answer to close this question.